# Unity constructor parameters

Tags: c#, unity-container

```
class Entity:IEntityName
{
    #region IEntityName Members

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

public class Person:IPerson
{
    public IEntityName EntityName;

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(IEntityName EntityName)
    {
        this.EntityName = EntityName;
    }

    public string ReverseName()
    {
        return string.Format("Your reverse name is {0} {1}",EntityName.LastName, EntityName.FirstName);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name is {0} {1}", EntityName.FirstName, EntityName.LastName);
    }
}

// Main Method

private static string DisplayReverseName(string fName,string lName)
{
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IPerson, Person>().RegisterType<IEntityName,Entity>();

        IEntityName entityName = container.Resolve<IEntityName>();

        entityName.FirstName = fName;
        entityName.LastName = lName;
        var p = container.Resolve<IPerson>(); 
        return p.ReverseName(); //  firstName and lastName are still null
    }
```

How can I inject the firstName and lastName into Person constructor ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing all of the work in a single method? (instantiating a container, setting up bindings, etc)

Comment: You are right I should have moved it out of the method. I was testing out few things with Unity for the first time...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a ParameterOverride like:

```
var p = container.Resolve<IPerson>(new ParameterOverride("EntityName", entityName));
```

This tells unity to supply the `entityName` instance to the constructor with the parameter named "EntityName".

You can find some additional info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660920(v=pandp.20).aspx