# Passing Constructor-Parameters to Unity-Container-Registration

Tags: c#, xamarin, unity-container

I have this registration-code in xamarin.forms with unity/prism:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IRepo, Repo>();
```

works, but now I change the Repo-Constructor to:

```
public Repo(string name)
```

how can I register that , and how to define the parameter name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758658/unity-constructor-parameters)

Comment: No, don't work in Xamarin/Prism